# What is a directed triangle?

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone explain to me what directed triangle is, or in general what a directed graph is? All the definitions I found were difficult to understand.

Comment: Which parts of, say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph are unclear?

Answer (score 1):

A graph $G$ is defined by its collection of vertices $V$ and collection of edges $E$.  We usually define $G = (V,E)$

The vertices can be any set of elements, it doesn't much matter.  It is common to only consider specifically finite sets for $V$ however there do exist also notions for graphs with infinite vertex-sets.  With an infinite vertex set one will usually clarify this by calling it an "Infinite Graph."  With a finite vertex set one might simply refer to it as a "Graph."

For a usual graph, the edge set is specifically going to be a subset of $\{\{u,v\}~:~u,v\in V, u\neq v\}$... that is to say each element of $E$ would be a two-element subset of $V$.  Note that here we do not allow for repeated edges and do not allow for one-element or three-element or any other number of element edges other than two.  Further, note that in an edge, the order of the elements is irrelevant.

If we choose to picture a graph, we can do so by drawing a dot for each vertex, labeling them with the name for each, and drawing a line from one vertex $v$ to another $u$ iff the edge $\{u,v\}$ exists in the edgeset $E$.

---

We can define a *directed* graph $\vec{G}$ with a vertex set $V$ and a *directed edge set* $\vec{E}$, that is $\vec{G}=(V,\vec{E})$.  *Directed edgesets* will not have their edges as two-element subsets of $V$, but will rather have their edges as *tuples* of elements of $V$.  That is, $\vec{E}$ is a subset of $\{(u,v)~:~u,v\in V,u\neq v\}$.  Note the distinction that $(1,2)\neq (2,1)$ despite $\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}$.  Note also, we still again don't allow for edges with only one end or more than two ends and still don't allow repeated edges...  Further, for usual directed graphs, if $(u,v)$ is in edge we do not allow $(v,u)$ to also be an edge.  There can be at most one edge between two vertices.

When drawing a picture of a directed graph, again we can use a dot for each vertex, but this time when drawing an edge $(u,v)$ we do so by drawing an *arrow* from the first vertex $u$ towards the second vertex $v$, the direction on the arrow being clearly visible.

I assume that a "directed triangle" is simply a directed graph isomorphic to $K_3$ with some arbitrary orientation on the edges, for example $(\{1,2,3\},\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\})$.

---

There are further generalizations or adjustments which can be made to graphs.  A short list of these possible adjustments might be to allow the edge-set to be a multiset instead, thus allowing duplicate / parallel edges (*multigraph*), allowing edges with only one endpoint or both ends as the same vertex (*"with loops" (also often considered in multigraphs)*), allowing edges to have some number of ends greater than two (*hypergraphs*), associating a color with vertices and/or edges (*colored graphs*), associating a value with vertices and/or edges (*weighted graphs*), and so on...